# How to include the counts for each character while removing the duplicates using itertools.groupby

Tags: python, string, pandas, python-itertools

I have the following code:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(data=all_r_1.to_dataframe().groupby(['user_id'])['type'].sum()).reset_index()

userid | type
20     | aab
21     | ababb
```

To remove the duplicates from the strings in the `type` column, I have this code:

```
df['type'] = df['type'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(ch for ch, _ in itertools.groupby(x)))
```

which produces this:

```
userid | type
20     | ab
21     | abab
```

This is the input df:

```
id | userid | type 
1  | 20     | a  
2  | 20     | a
3  | 20     | b
4  | 21     | a  
5  | 21     | b
6  | 21     | a
7  | 21     | b
8  | 21     | b
```

However, what I want to do is to include the counts for each character while removing the duplicates:

```
userid | type
20     | a2b
21     | abab2
```

Any ideas how I can modify the `itertools.groupby` code to also include the counts?

Comment: try this: 
`df['type'] = df['type'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(ch+len(list(group)) for ch, group in itertools.groupby(x)))`

Comment: @Chris_Rands thanks! I got this error `TypeError: object of type 'itertools._grouper' has no len()`

Comment: Did you put `len(list(group))`? (I edited this into my original comment)

Comment: @Chris_Rands yes it worked, but I needed to convert it to `str`. Could you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertools.groupby` stores the actual groups so you can access this as follows:

```
df['type'] = df['type'].apply(lambda x: ''.join('{}{}'.format(ch,len(list(group))) for ch, group in itertools.groupby(x)))
```